# display more than one HTML document in the same browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, wiki

So basically I am working on a wiki and there are some tables in different parts of the wiki that I would like to display on a main page. I know I can copy and paste them but I would like to make it so that when those tables get updated my main page is automatically updated with the new values. Is there a way to do this? Oh the wiki can do HTML and CSS.

Comment: What kind of Dynamic HTML are you using on the server side (e.g. PHP, ASP.NET, Java)?

Comment: Thanks guys. I think iframe will solve me problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use IFrame. `<iframe id="abc" src="path of other html"/>`

Answer (score 0):

A good wiki will segment the content elements so that they can be displayed on multiple pages but only require one source. Whether that feature exists in your Wiki or not isn't something we can answer without knowing what it is.

Otherwise, the iFrame solution would work, but it'll load the entire wiki page that contains the table...not just the table itself. Plus, iFrames can introduce other issues such as printing difficulties in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of options.  You can store the table data in a database if it's going to be constantly updated. You can store it in a flat file. You can include() your table pages in the main page. Whichever works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

1. On the main page use div-element to create a "box" for each table.
2. Fill each box with a "transclude" to the table page.
3. At the table page place the table between onlyinclude tags.

Example:

> ```
> <div style="border: 1px solid grey; ">
> ==Table1==
> {{:tablepage1}}</div>
> <div style="border: 1px solid grey; ">
> ==Table2==
> {{:tablepage2}}</div>
> ```